Does a section of a finite-measure set in the product measure space have a finite measure almost everywhere?
Let $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T},\nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, and $\mu\otimes\nu$ the product measure on the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{T}$. Let $M\in\mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{T}$, $x\in X$, and
$$M_x=\{ y\in Y\mid(x,y)\in M\}.$$
If $(\mu\otimes\nu)(M)<\infty$, what can I say about the finiteness of $\nu(M_x)$ ? My guess is that $\nu(M_x)<\infty$ for almost every $x\in X$, but is this true?

$$\mu \otimes \nu (M) = \int \nu(M_x)\mu(dx)$$

@Andrew That is certainly a very succinct argument, but I would appreciate a more elementary argument...

@ashpool Proving that is pretty much how one proves Fubini's theorem, starting from indicator functions. It is as direct as it gets.

I think this is the simplest way to prove it:
Let $M\in\mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{T}$, and let $\chi_M$ be the characteristic function of $M$.  Then, applying Tonelli's Theorem:
$$
\int \nu(M_x) d \mu = \int \left (\int \chi_{M_x} d \nu \right) d \mu = \int \chi_M d (\mu \otimes \nu) = (\mu\otimes\nu)(M)<\infty
$$
So the function $x \mapsto \nu(M_x)$ is a non-negative function and $\int \nu(M_x) d \mu <\infty$. It follows immediately that $x \mapsto \nu(M_x)$ is finite $\mu$-almost-everywhere.
$\square$
Another solution would be essentially to redo the prove of Tonelli's theorem for characteristic functions. But, it would not be a "simpler proof".

This answer is merely a slight elaboration of Ramiro's answer: $\chi_M$ is integrable, so by Fubini-Tonelli theorem,
$$\iint \chi_M\,d\nu\,d\mu=\int\chi_M\,d(\mu\otimes\nu)=(\mu\otimes\nu)(M).$$
In particular, there exists a null set $E\in\mathcal{S}$ and an integrable function $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for each $x\in X-E$, the function
$$(\chi_M)_x:Y\to\mathbb{R},\qquad  y\mapsto\chi_M(x,y)$$
is integrable and $\int(\chi_M)_x\,d\nu=g(x)$.
Since $(\chi_M)_x=\chi_{M_Y(x)}$, it follows that $\nu(M_Y(x))=g(x)$ for each $x\in X-E$, i.e., $\nu(M_Y(x))<\infty$ for almost every $x\in X$.
